# Bash one-liner to save to file then use content

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to do something like this:

1. save command1 output to file
2. feed same output to command2

something like this

```
   command2 $(command1 > file.txt)
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `tee`. This copies its standard input to a file and also its standard output. Then pipe the output to the second command.

```
command1 | tee file.txt | command2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question used

```
command2 $(command1 > file.txt)
```

`tee` pipes are great, but if I read this right, `command2` expects a filename?
If so, maybe you can use

```
command2 <( command1 )
```

If you *also* need the file, then `tee` inside the construct -

```
command2 <( command1 | tee file.txt )
```

If for some strange reason it absolutely requires a file NAME (can't really imagine why), then you could always try this as a last resort -

```
command2 "$( command1 > file.txt && echo file.txt )"
```